# Export Proxy for Git on Centos 6.3

Tags: git, proxy, centos

I'm using a Server with Centos 6.3

I would like to clone something from git and I'm behind a proxy...

The command to export the proxy:

```
git config --global http.proxy some.proxy
```

does not work...

I'll get this error back:

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Some Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

export the proxy in /etc/envoirements

```
http_proxy=http://someusername:somepass@someproxy.com:port
https_proxy=https://someusername:somepass@someproxy.com:port
```

Answer (score 0):

> **http**.proxy

> **ssh**: connect to host github.com **port 22**

See the difference? SSH won't go through HTTP proxy. The easiest soultion is to use GitHub's HTTPS protocol instead.

Comment: @ciaodarwin Are you sure your proxy settings are correct? Have you checked the repo URL?

Comment: yes they are! the URL exists...

I will download the zip-file to my computer and copy them to my server(noob-way)